# can't compile play showcase html

Tags: gwt, maven, playn

I installed playN however I get this error:

[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:compile (default) @ playn-showcase-html ---
[ERROR] Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler

I checked the m2 repository, and the gwt jars for 2.4 2.5 gwt seem to be there.

If I try to use GWT 2.5 in the project then I get this

The GWT SDK 'C:\Users\user.m2\repository\com\google\gwt' on the project's build path is not valid (Version  is not supported, must be 2.0.0 or later)
playn-showcase-html
Unknown Google Web Toolkit Problem

Does this make sense at all?
How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Try using mvn -e -X to find out error/debug log in detail. Verify whether gwt-dev jar is in class path.

Comment: 1) Installed http://git-scm.com/ 2) Git Clone as from http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Running_via_Maven 3) Import to Eclipse with M2E & GPE & Android plugins. It works as is!!! I am guessing your maven installation is corrupted or non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some gwt jars in the maven repository were corrupted. I deleted them, i run the playN sample again, the jars were downloaded correctly, and the whole think worked

Comment: I had the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\Users\user.m2` <-- this is very strange.  it looks like somehow your maven repository path is munged up.

Check your environmental variables for `MAVEN_REPOSITORY` and see if its set to `C:\Users\user`. Also, find your maven installation directory, and look under the `conf` directory for a `settings.xml`, and see if you have `<localRepository>${env.MAVEN_REPOSITORY}/.m2/repository</localRepository>`.

Comment: Your initial observation is spot on. However, Should it be MAVEN_REPOSITORY or M2_REPO and it directly holds the path upto <userhome>/.m2/repository !!!! so ${env.MAVEN_REPOSITORY}/.m2/repository seems a bit non-standard.

Comment: Thanks for the help, yes the M2_REPO environment variable was set correctly (+1)